# Sass @use does not work in CSS modules in React, while import does

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, css-modules

I have generated a React project with `create-react-app` using the TypeScript template. I've installed Sass via `npm install sass`, while CSS modules were already supported by the generated template.

I've created a common set of variables within the `styles/common.scss` file. I wanted to import and use the variables from the file in the stylesheet of my component. The recommended way to do this seems to be the `@use` directive, but I was unable to get to work.

Relevant files within my project structure:

```
components/
  custom/
    Custom.module.scss
    Custom.tsx
styles/
  common.scss
```

In this scenario `components/custom/Custom.module.scss` tries to import and use a variable from `styles/common.scss` with `@use "styles/common.scss"`. While I don't get any specific errors related to the `@use` directive, attempting to reference any variables from the common stylesheet results in the following error: `SassError: Undefined variable.`

Things I've tried so far:

- Proceeding the path with `~`: `@use "~styles/common.scss"` yields the same error.
- Different combinations of adding underscore to the common stylesheet, as well as removing extensions from the path in `@use`: same results.
- Replacing `@use` with `@import "styles/common.scss"` works as expected: the variables are available in the CSS module.

However, since the `@import` is set to be deprecated, I'm wondering how to get `@use` to work and what is the root of the issue. Note that CSS modules themselves work as expected, and I'm able to import them correctly within the `tsx` files.

Comment: You have to forward files in order to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a default `create-react-app` setup, the correct way to import a module via `@use` is to omit the file extension (`.scss`) and the proceeding underscore. So, for example, `styles/_colors.scss` can be imported with `@use "styles/colors"`.

However, by default each variable (etc.) from the imported file will require a prefix to be used. So, for example, to reference `$pink` from the imported `_colors.scss` file, you'd have to write `colors.$pink`. To change the prefix, you can choose an alias with `as` in the `@use` directive. For example, `@use "styles/colors" as c;` would allow the variables to be accessed with a `c.` prefix. To remove the prefix altogether, use the `*` alias.

Additionally, adding an `_index.scss` file allows using entire folders with specifying individual files. Use `@forward` directive in the `_index.scss` to choose which modules are available when importing the folder.

So, to sum it up, the file structure should look roughly like this:

- `styles/_colors.scss`

```scss
$pink: #ff00ff;
```

- `styles/_index.scss`: optional, allows importing multiple modules in 1 step.

```scss
@forward "styles/colors";
```

- `components/custom/Custom.module.css`

```scss
@use "styles" as *;
// Or: @use "styles/colors" as *;

// Now $pink can be referenced without an alias.
```